# How to delete part of shape in Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I have two shapes on two different layers. I want to crop the only the part of image only according to the shape on layer 1. I want to keep part of shape on layer 2 which is in the layer1 shape area and want to remove all area outside the shape1.

Please see the following image for better understanding:
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Step 1

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + **Click** the thumbnail of **Layer 2**

[image]

## Step 2

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + **Click** the thumbnail of **Layer 1**. This will give you the `intersection` of the 2 shapes.
[image]

**Voila!** You'll have a selection of the shape you want.

If you are trying to keep your shapes intact, then still do the above, but then do the following:

- **Right-Click** the selection created in Step 2
- Go to **Make Work Path...**
- Set the `Tolerance` to something low like `0.5`

Now you'll have a new Path from the selection and your shapes will remain intact.

## Result

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for such a detailed answer. It was very helpful to me.

Comment: No problem, welcome to GD!

Answer (score 2):

I will piggyback off [ckpepper02's answer](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/21383/408) but I will use shapes with vector masks instead of rasterized shapes. I will also use layer masks to be non-destructive.

Let's say you have this image here:

[image]

Your layers would look like this:

[image]

`CTRL-Click` the top layer's vector mask.
Then `CTRL-ALT-SHIFT-Click` the bottom layer's vector mask.

That will select the intersection of the two layers.

Now select the top layer, and click `Add layer mask` at the bottom of the layer's panel.

[image]

[image]

Here's the final result:

[image]

The added benefit of the layer mask means we do not have to destroy any data. We can, at any time, get back to full shape, or adjust it further if we'd like. If you're unfamiliar with layer masks, [I'd suggest you read this quick article to get a better idea.](http://wegraphics.net/blog/tutorials/photoshop/photoshop-for-beginners-understanding-layer-mask/)

Also, with this technique we can keep our vector masks as well and we don't need to rasterize our layers.

Comment: Thank you so much for such a wonderful answer. It helped me a lot. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a vector mask based on shape 1 for non destructive 'cropping' of the layer 2 shape.